# PHP random sorting

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am executing a query which returns me an array of 10 items.

Example

> [1,20,4,9,56,88,64,12,33,18]

How is the easiest way to randomly sort them with no rules and separate it in 2 arrays?

Comment: You can use array sort function. http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: @dante, did you spend any time looking through php's online list of array functions?  This page is very easy to scroll through: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_array.asp  Please do your own research before posting such a simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For randomly sort use `shuffle($array);` and for 2 array use `array_chunk()`